# Are attribute selectors still less efficient than class selectors if we're targeting many classes?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to figure out whether it makes more sense to use an attribute selector that looks for a specific prefix vs. handwriting each class selector that needs the styles. Example:

```
[class^=c2] {
  ... 
}
```

vs.

```
.c2-1, .c2-2, .c2-3, .c2-4, [...] , .c2-9999 {
  ...
}
```

I know that attribute selectors are [less efficient](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/), but are they still less efficient when the alternative is writing out hundreds of classes? I'm pushing this to its logical extreme because I need to write nested classes as  well, meaning that not using the attr selector would result in 100-200 handwritten classes.

EDIT: Another constraint: you can't change markup or add extra classes.

Comment: The efficiency lost by using `[class^=c2]` is offset by the amount of time spent stressing out over how inefficient it is.

Comment: @cimmanon: And even by the amount of time spent typing out (or copying and pasting) the class selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this varies on page load, browser, etc. We tested the difference using http://stevesouders.com/efws/css-selectors/csscreate.php

Answer (score 0):

sorry, but what about adding a class `.c2` to every element?
that would definitely be the fastest and most logical way.

Comment: I imagine because you can't start a class with a number, i.e. `.c4.1, .c4.2`

Comment: Good thought, I forgot to mention that the constraint is you can't change the markup/only use one class. It just has to do with the application (I don't want to have to programmatically insert markup).